# Using a different font for each major mode

Tags: major-mode, fonts

Is it possible to set different fonts following the major mode? Say `Inconsolata-12` in `org-mode` buffers and `Symbola-12` in all remaining modes. 
Or at least, is it possible to do a

```
(set-frame-font "Inconsolata" t)
```

after switching to `org-mode` buffers?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`buffer-face-set` and `buffer-face-mode` in Emacs 23 or later is designed for exactly this. From the [Emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FacesPerBuffer#toc3):

```
;; Use variable width font faces in current buffer
 (defun my-buffer-face-mode-variable ()
   "Set font to a variable width (proportional) fonts in current buffer"
   (interactive)
   (setq buffer-face-mode-face '(:family "Symbola" :height 100 :width semi-condensed))
   (buffer-face-mode))

 ;; Use monospaced font faces in current buffer
 (defun my-buffer-face-mode-fixed ()
   "Sets a fixed width (monospace) font in current buffer"
   (interactive)
   (setq buffer-face-mode-face '(:family "Inconsolata" :height 100))
   (buffer-face-mode))

 ;; Set default font faces for Info and ERC modes
 (add-hook 'erc-mode-hook 'my-buffer-face-mode-variable)
 (add-hook 'Info-mode-hook 'my-buffer-face-mode-variable)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do the change by using the `org-mode-hook`, like this

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (set-frame-font "Inconsolata" t)))
```

Which will change the font whenever you enter org mode. The downside is that it doesn't change the font back after you leave org mode.

Edit: as pointed out by [Ryan](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/35/ryan), you can follow the advice on [this wiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FacesPerBuffer) to do it per buffer. I haven't tested extensively, but this seems to work

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda ()
                            (setq buffer-face-mode-face '(:family "Inconsolata"))
                            (buffer-face-mode)))
```

It might have issues if you want to use `buffer-face-mode` in other buffers, but if you only use it for this then it should work.

Comment: Have you looked at `buffer-face-set`? [This wiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FacesPerBuffer) indicates you can do the same thing per buffer instead of per frame.

Comment: Great, thanks, this is exactly was I was looking for. This community is extraordinary.